# Arduino creating delay function

Tags: c, time, arduino

I am trying to make my own delay function. Briefly `mydelay` function is calling `toggled` function every `secs` seconds. The code is not well written, i know (this is the first version). But i am just trying to get it work properly. Then i will refactor it. But i have some unexpected bugs. First time the loop in `x` function is working properly. It is printing "I am in while" for 1 second and then it prints "Im ending mydelay" which is the behaviour i want. But after finishing the loop in `x`. The second time when it loops. It enters the `mydelay` function (that is ok). But then it is not printing "I am in while" at all. It just prints "Im ending mydelay" which is not good.

Here is the code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
int led = 7;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  x();
  Serial.println("Im ending main loop");
}

void x() {
  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    mydelay(led, 0, 1);
    mydelay(led, 1, 1);
  }
}

void mydelay(int pin, int hol, int secs) {
  int starttime = millis();
  while ((millis() - starttime) <= (secs * 1000)) Serial.println("I am in while");
  toggled(pin, hol);
  Serial.println("Im ending mydelay");
}

void toggled(int pin, int hol) {
  digitalWrite(led, hol);
}
```

Comment: I think that the problem might be with **millis**, that will keep returning milliseconds since  the arduino begins the  program, I think eventually millis-starttime will be larger than secs * 1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `int starttime = millis();` to `unsigned long starttime = millis();`. This **might** be the problem because if you are using an `int`, your program will go crazy after 32 seconds. That is a problem because an `int` can only hold a number going from -32,768 to 32,767 .

Also, you might as well try this:

```
while ((millis() - starttime) <= (secs * 1000))
{
  Serial.println("I am in while");
}
```

Comment: Yea... I actually printed `(millis() - starttime)` and at the last time (when it started going nuts) the last value was 65536 which is 2^16.And i tought what has this to do with 2^16 (i forgot that arduino is 16-bit).Anyways thanks!

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try to reset the millis using something like this, I don't have an arduino so it's not tested but hopefully it can help.

```
extern volatile unsigned long timer0_millis;
unsigned long reset = 0;

#include <Arduino.h>
int led = 7;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  x();
  Serial.println("Im ending main loop");

  setMillis(reset);
}

void setMillis(unsigned long new_millis){
  uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
  cli();
  timer0_millis = new_millis;
  SREG = oldSREG;
}

void x() {
  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    mydelay(led, 0, 1);
    mydelay(led, 1, 1);
  }
}

void mydelay(int pin, int hol, int secs) {
  int starttime = millis();
  while ((millis() - starttime) <= (secs * 1000)) Serial.println("I am in while");
  toggled(pin, hol);
  Serial.println("Im ending mydelay");
}

void toggled(int pin, int hol) {
  digitalWrite(led, hol);
}
```